# What was the creature that was chasing Defender Strange at the start of the movie?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In the start of the movie,

> we see a ribboned(?) creature chasing after Defender Strange and America Chavez in the space between universes. What exactly was it ? Is it based off of a comic character ?

The creature: https://bgr.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/doctor-strange-2-trailer-2-super-bowl-2.jpg

Comment: It's identified within the Marvel Cinematic Universe Wiki as the '[Ribboned Creature](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Ribboned_Creature)'. There's no identification as yet from an official source, though there may well be within a few weeks, when the staff who worked on this movie are allowed to discuss spoilers. I don't personally recognise it as corresponding to anything in the comics, and if it did, the Marvel Cinematic Universe Wiki would likely mention that, but it doesn't.

Comment: For now it’s just the Ribboned Creature, but I’m sure before long someone will come forward and put a bow on it

Answer (score 4):

Now I am NOT very sure but according to fan theories and [this particular screenrant article](https://screenrant.com/multiverse-of-madness-best-x-men-references/), the ribbon creature is the Demigod **Cyttorak**

> In the opening scene of the movie, fans saw a variant of Doctor Strange being chased by a demon called Cyttorak.

Further proof to support this theory is that Dr Strange is shown using the spell - "The crimson bands of cyttorak" on Thanos in *Avengers: Infinity War* (2018) and it looked similar to the creature shown in the this movie.