# Why did this character need America Chavez?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

Early in the movie, it is revealed that

> Scarlet Witch is the antagonist of the movie who wants to take America Chavez's power so that she can travel across the multiverse.

However, we do see her summon [some ribboned creature](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263075/what-was-the-creature-chasing-defender-strange-at-the-start-of-the-movie) and Gargantos/Shuma Gorath who are said to be inter-dimensional beings. So she does already have the power to send creatures across the multiverse, couldn't she send herself ? Or if we say, that she can only summon, couldn't she dreamwalk into one of the Wandas in the other universes and summon herself ?

Comment: "she does already have the power to send creatures across the multiverse" — she might not be able to *send* creatures into other universes; maybe she can just communicate with them, and try to get them to do her bidding. We don't know how much control she can exert over these creatures, and the two we saw were foiled by Doctor Strange and Wong, so apparently it's not a hugely effective tactic.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: During Strange's conversation with Mordo (838), they talk about the power of the DarkHold and how it can "summon" monsters before moving on to the topic of Dreamwalking...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Travelling the multi-verse is difficult, even for someone who

> possesses the Darkhold. Which really only allows a sort-of 'projection' and only allows 'possession' via the Dreamwalking mechanic (which in itself is also very limited).

The character wanted this be **final**.

Additionally, as explained in the movie when questioned about this motivation:

> Wanda felt that she needed America's powers to help her children, in the case that they get sick. She says "In the infinite universes, there are infinite cures for *any* illness." (paraphrased from memory).

The character feels a deep sense of desperation to get - but more importantly - *keep* the objectives.

Answer (score 10):

The fact that Wanda was able to get the [Ribboned Creature](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Ribboned_Creature) and [Gargantos](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Gargantos) to pursue America Chavez doesn't prove she can summon anyone she wants from other universes, or send anyone anywhere.

As things stand, we have no way of knowing for sure, but if we're trying to make sense of things, my guess would be that the Darkhold contained spells which allowed her to summon and/or control *those creatures specifically*, and perhaps some other specific entities, but not just any random person of her choice. That'd explain why she couldn't do what you proposed as an alternative to stealing America's powers.

In time, more information from official sources may come to light on this, but this close to release, we have very little to work with other than the film itself.